# C++ inheritance problem

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Here are my classes:

> ParentClass, ParentObj
>
> DerivedClass (inherits from ParentClass), DerivedObj (inherits from ParentObj).

ParentClass has a protected member:

> std::vector< ParentObj* >

DerivedClass allocates only DerivedObj* objects to this vector.

Problem is:

When I use ParentClass, I want to access its vector objects with an iterator of type:

> std::vector< ParentObj* >::const_iterator

And when I use DerivedClass, I want to access its vector objects with an iterator of type:

> std::vector< DerivedObj* >::const_iterator

How can I make it work?

Comment: You should not use pointer elements within a STL container unless you are 100% sure that noone EVER is going to modify it (for example with std::sort...)! STL container do have value semantics and copying is never a good thing with pointers!

Comment: I don't see the problem with `std::sort`... I would rather have spoken about `::erase()` methods or something like that :/

Comment: @fmuecke: you have to treat pointers as pointers, coping properly with ownership issues, and differentiate between 'copying' and 'cloning'.  (or shallow vs. deep copy).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a virtual override in your `DerivedClass` class returning a subtype of the `ParentClass` return type...

```
struct ParentClass {
    virtual ParentObj* get( const size_t index ) {
       return m_objects[index];
    }
 };

 struct DerivedClass : public ParentClass {
    virtual DerivedObj* get( const size_t index ) {
       return dynamic_cast<DerivedObj*>( ParentClass::get(index) );
    }
 };
```

Both functions are the same 'vtable' entry, though their return type differs.

Alternatively, you may use the same technique to create 'inherited' iterators.

Next to that, it's not a bad idea to have a vector of `DerivedObj*`'s in the `DerivedClass` object, as long as you guarantee that they are also present in the `ParentClass`'s vector.

Comment: +1, providing get() method looks nice and restricts casting to only this function.

Comment: That's a good idea if I don't work with the vector's iterators...

By the way, I didn't know you can overload a method with a different return value, interesting.

Comment: If the class has suitable invariants (for instance, pointers are only added to the vector via a virtual member function overridden in DerivedClass), you could make that a static_cast. Type erasure, basically.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It still doesn't sound like a good code practice (and it appears in a lot of places in the code).

Comment: @Jack, returning a subtype of the original return type in an overridden virtual method is referred to as a covariant return type. It isn't overloading as such.

Comment: You can override if the overriding type is derived from the overriden... however since this is not true for the iterators it won't work that well :/

Answer (score 2):

I have a question there: *Why does `DerivedClass` inherits from `ParentClass` ?*

Do you need a polymorphic behavior, or do you want to reuse the implementation of `ParentClass` ?

Inheritance is often badly misused. Really.

Then there is the (typical) problem of having a container class, and how to expose its elements. Unfortunately the iterators are (despite all their goods) poorly supported by the language unlike the pointers they are supposed to emulate.

So, a reminder: **Inheritance** is a **is-a** relationship, for code reuse there is **Composition**.

Here you could perfectly write a template class that would play the part of the container and provide common methods.

Then, for the problem of exposition... you can write your own iterators, with the correct base-derived relationship, or you can opt to preselect a number of algorithms (`sort`, `foreach`, `erase_if`) that would work with user-supplied predicates.

```
template <class Value>
class Container
{
public:
  template <class Pred>
  void sort(Pred iPred);

  template <class Pred>
  Pred foreach(Pred iPred); // maybe a const-version ?

  template <class Pred>
  size_t erase_if(Pred iPred); // returns the number of erased
private:
  std::vector<Value> m_data;
};
```

Then, on to your classes:

```
class ParentClass
{
public:
  virtual void foo() const;
private:
  Container<ParentObj*> m_data;
};

class DerivedClass: public ParentClass
{
public:
  virtual void foo() const;
private:
  Container<DerivedObj*> m_data;
};
```

Try to separate polymorphism from code reuse, and the problem should get simpler.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector< ParentObj* >` and `std::vector< DerivedObj* >` are two totally different types hence you can not implicitly convert one to another. What you can do is convert each `ParentObj*` to `DerivedObj*` using `dynamic_cast`. But generally it is not considered a good practice.

Comment: I know, that's what I do now... No other way?
I thought of having vector<ParentObj*> a private member and DerivedClass will have a private member of its own: vector<DerivedObj*>, but this is also not very elegant...

Comment: I think the better practice here is to add a virtual function on the objects that does what is needed. Thus call it on the ParentObj* and runtie will choose to call the function defined on ParentObj or DerivedObj

Comment: Interesting idea.
> virtual void derivedObjDoesSomething() { assert(0); }
I'll think about it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using basic C++ inheritance. The reason is that the compiler doesn't know that the vector contains only pointers to `DerivedObj` when used in `DerivedClass`. I second Naveens statement about dynamic cast.

You could use two vectors `std::vector< ParentObj* > mParent` and `std::vector< DerivedObj* > mDerived` and a virtual `Add()` function. The base implementation would add only to `mParent`. The `Add` function in `DerivedClass` would also add to `mDerived`.

`ParentClass` would have a `GetParentIterator()` function and `DerivedClass` would have another (additional) function `GetDerivedIterator()`.

Answer (score -1):

Your inheritance design is wrong.

`DerivedClass` must not inherit from `ParentClass`.
`ParentClass` has a protected member `std::vector< ParentObj* >`.
And `DerivedClass` must have another protected member `std::vector< DerivedObj* >`.

You may create template class

```
template<class T>
struct MyClass {
  protected:
    std::vector< T* > m_objects;
};

struct ParentClass : MyClass <ParentObj> {};
struct DerivedClass: MyClass <DerivedObj> {};
```

Comment: What does it change ? Why a protected member anyway, that beats the purpose of encapsulation...

Comment: How is this any different from struct ParentClass {std::vector<ParentObj*> m_objects;}; and struct DerivedClass {std::vector<DerivedObj*> m_objects;}; I.e. two unrelated classes?

Comment: Yes! unrelated classes. It is better than inheritance. If you want to have common functions you have to make a common base class.